# If $X$ is a compact metric space and $A$ is a subset of the metric space $C(X,\mathbb{C})$, then the uniform closure of $A$ is $\overline{A}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

While reading Rudin, I came across this. Is this true? I can't seem to find a reference for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\overline{A}$ is just the notation for the closure of $A$. I don't see anything to prove here.

Answer (score 0):

This is true by Heine's theorem (every function continuous on a compact metric space with values in a metric space is uniformly continuous, thus your notion of "uniform closure" coincides with that of "closure" - assuming you're considering the usual norm $||f||=sup_{x \in X}(|f(x)|)$).

Comment: The statement in the title appears to just be a definition. If so, why would we need a theorem for it to be true? Perhaps you mean that the definition is motivated by the theorem?

Comment: I assumed that by $\overline{A}$ he meant the usual closure while the statement in the title refers to the notion of "uniform closure". But I agree that the statement is awkward and looks like a definition.

Comment: Sorry, but what is the "usual closure" if not the uniform closure given that we are working with the metric induced by the sup-norm?

Comment: They do coincide, but I assumed this to be unknown (which is precisely why the Heine theorem would then be needed).

Comment: Said differently: if we assume that every function in $A$ is bounded and that $X$ is not compact, then the $sup$ norm is still defined but in that case the closure does not necessarily coincide with the uniform closure anymore...

Comment: But isn't that because "closure" is meaningless in that context, given that the the sup-norm does not induce a metric on the set of continuous functions on $X$?

Comment: That said, regardless of what your last comment could possibly mean, that situation isn't really relevant. We are working in a space of continuous functions on a compact set endowed with the uniform norm. In this setting, "uniform closure" and "closure" are the same *by definition*. Appealing to a theorem to say that they are equivalent doesn't make sense at all.